# PDF files do not open in Chome Browse

Tags: pdf

I am using Chrome on Windows 7 pro 64 bit ver.  Recently, past couple weeks, PDF files that I could open on web pages stopped displaying the content.  It only display a black background in the window.  They work correctly in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Type:

> chrome://plugins/

in the url bar, and search for **Chrome PDF Viewer** plugin.

Check to see if you can click in "Enable".